# Python - Combining two arrays based on criteria

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to combine two numpy 2D arrays into one array based off a certain criteria for e.g.

```
# array1
[1,2,3,4,5]
[10,11,12,13,14]

# array2
[15,16,17,18,19]
[6,7,8,9,10]
```

The resulting combination of array 1 and array 2 based off the criteria - highest value - would look like below;

```
[15,16,17,18,19]
[10,11,12,13,14]
```

I know how to concatenate two arrays together, filter but I can't seem to find a function that would provide me the above result.

Perhaps a variation on `np.where`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), for arrays `a` and `b`, you can use:

```
np.where(a>b, a, b)
```

For your example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13,14]])
>>> b = np.array([[15,16,17,18,19],[6,7,8,9,10]])
>>> np.where(a>b, a, b)
array([[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html):

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[10,11,12,13,14]])
a2 = np.array([[15,16,17,18,19],[10,11,12,13,14]])

print(np.maximum(a1, a2))
# [[15 16 17 18 19]
#  [10 11 12 13 14]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I was only previously aware of being able to produce a new array by filtering.